# Why did Rose run from the police?

Tags: plot-explanation, silent-hill

In Silent Hill, as Rose and her daughter are reaching the town, a female cop stops her. Rose decides to run off, crashing her car and leading to a lot of other events.

Why did Rose run from the cop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why did Rose run from the cop?

When Rose is at the gas station, she talks to the cashier about Silent Hill. The clerk says that the road to Silent Hill is closed off.

When Rose gets pulled over by the cop, she assumes the cop will ask where Rose is headed and will tell her to turn around.

Therefore, Rose sped off from the cop because she was determined to get to Silent Hill, and she knew the cop would tell her to turn around (and possibly even escort her back to the nearest town, or something similar).